# Appending List[Database]

Tags: scala, lift

I am new with Scala and I am writing a simple rss reader.
I have class Manager for managing feeds and content.

```
package lib
import scala.xml._
import java.net.URL
import net.liftweb.couchdb.{CouchDB, Database}
import dispatch.{Http, StatusCode}

/**
 * @author smix
 * 
 * Feeds manager
 */
object Manager {
 var db = List[Database]()
 /*
  * Initialize CouchDb databases
  */
 def init = {
  this.appendDb(new Database("myserver.com", 5984, "content"))
 }

 /*
  * Append a new database to the databases list
  */
 private def appendDb(database: Database) : Unit = {
  database :: db 
  // Strange exception if database has been already created
  /* try {
   this.db.head.createIfNotCreated(new Http())
  } catch {
   case e:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError => {}
  } */
 }

 /*
  * Fetch articles from feed by url
  */
    def fetchItems(feedUrl: String): List[scala.xml.Elem] = { 
   val rssFeed = XML.load( (new URL(feedUrl)).openConnection.getInputStream )
   val items = rssFeed \ "channel" \ "item"

   val articles: List[scala.xml.Elem] = List()
   for(item <- items) {
      item :: articles
   }

   articles
    }

}
```

I want to store content in CouchDb. I need to have list of couch databases(feeds, articles, etc...). I wrote class but when I call appendDb i get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lib/Manager$
 at collector$.main(collector.scala:5)
 at collector.main(collector.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lib.Manager$
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 ... 2 more
```

When I rewrited `db` definition: `var db = List[Int]()` and the first line of appendDb: `1 :: this.db` project ran fine... Strange.

Also, it is interesting why am I getting exception when I call createIfNotCreated for existing database(commented try-catch block in appendDb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception indicates that you're missing some classes (one or more JAR files, presumably) when you run your program, though they're either irrelevant to compiling it or they *are* available then.

You should also note that the first line in `appendDb` accomplishes nothing. It builds a new `List` by consing `database` onto the front of the `List` referred to by `db`, but the resulting value is discarded. Perhaps you meant this:

```
  db = database :: db
```